# How would i create a private text channel using discord.py?

Tags: discord.py

I want to make it so when a member says: !contact, it opens a private text channel that only the creator can see, as well as the admins. I am very new to discord.py so sorry if this seems like a basic question. Ik there are other questions like this, but none of them seem to work, they say "guild is not defined"

Edit: sorry for not providing code

Comment: What is the code you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When posting questions on StackOverflow, you should always try to give examples of what code you have been trying and what you're confused over. Our purpose by answering your questions is to give you a better understanding of a topic and to make sure that you understand what you did wrong, and how to improve.

To get an [instance of the current guild](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#guild) that the command is being run in, you can utilize the [command context's guild property](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context.guild). Once we have an instance of the guild, we can [create a text channel](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.create_text_channel) and specify permissions that we want the channel to have. When specifying the channel overwrites, you use a dictionary to map either a [role](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#role) or [member](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#member) to [permission overwrite](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.PermissionOverwrite).

```py
import discord

@client.command()
async def contact(ctx):
    guild = ctx.guild
    admin_role = guild.get_role(0)  # Replace with id of admin role
    
    overwrites = {
        guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(view_channel=False),
        ctx.author: discord.PermissionOverwrite(view_channel=True),
        admin_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(view_channel=True),
        guild.me: discord.PermissionOverwrite(view_channel=True)
    }

    await guild.create_text_channel("private-channel", overwrites=overwrites)  # Replace with name of text channel
```